# Same slot content for multiple template slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

In vuejs, is there a way to set the same content for multiple slots without copy pasting?

So this:

```
<base-layout>
  <template slot="option">
    <span :class="'flag-icon-'   props.option.toLowerCase()" />{{ countriesByCode[props.option] }}
  </template>

  <template slot="singleLabel">
    <span :class="'flag-icon-'   props.option.toLowerCase()" />{{ countriesByCode[props.option] }}
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

Could be written that way:

```
<base-layout>
  <template slot="['option', 'singleLabel']">
    <span :class="'flag-icon-'   props.option.toLowerCase()" />{{ countriesByCode[props.option] }}
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please indicate that you are using Vuejs, as i see the question is for use it as native html

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I've made that more clear in the question (using vue as a tag seemed ok to me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component) for that.

```html
<base-layout>
  <template :slot="slotName" v-for="slotName in ['option', 'singleLabel']">
    <span :class="'flag-icon-'   props.option.toLowerCase()" />{{ countriesByCode[props.option] }}
  </template>
</base-layout>
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nz3mnmq2m).

Comment: I've added `slot-scope="props"` to the `<template/>` tag (I've forget this in my question). I hadn't thought about a for loop, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092116/3740945) is no longer valid and currently generates errors.

Here is what currently valid code would look like:

```js
<base-layout>
  <template v-for="slotName in ['option', 'singleLabel']" v-slot:[slotName] :key="slotName">
    <span :class="'flag-icon-'   props.option.toLowerCase()" />{{ countriesByCode[props.option] }}
  </template>
</base-layout>
```