# Overwrite template slot dynamically

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuetify.js, belongs-to

Fetching some headers config from a `belongsTo()` relation from Laravel. The responses looks like this:

[image: API Response]

My [Vuetify data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) config is this one:

```
    <v-data-table
            :headers="newHeaders"
            :items="products"
            item-key="name"
        >
      <template v-slot:header.stocks.0.pivot.quantity="{ header }">
        {{ header.text }}
        <v-icon>
          mdi-pencil-outline
        </v-icon>
      </template>
   </v-data-table>
```

I just want to use the slot to add my icon 'dynamically' to all 'Stock' headers adding (Could be 1, 2 3 or more headers).

How can I achieve this feature? I mean, right now is statically because if another stock is added I have to use `<template v-slot:header.stocks.1.pivot.quantity="{ header }">` to do it.

**Edited:**
This is how the table looks like:

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Are you saying that the number of columns changes dynamically based on your API call results? Could you provide more details about what the final table is supposed to look like (i.e. a mockup or detailed description)? I think there's a way to solve your problem, but the approach is different than what you've described so far.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @morphatic The API can add new Stocks for this Product (Relationship), it means a new Column is added the next time you refresh the page. But if I need to 'modify' the header with the slot from vuetify I do `<template v-slot:header.stocks.2.pivot.quantity="{ header }">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a solution from this answer: [Same slot content for multiple template slots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092116/9555152) It was a kind of gorgeous and this is my solution:

**Template tag**

```
  <v-data-table
        :headers="newHeaders"
        :items="products"
        item-key="name"
    >
  <template 
     :slot="slotName"
     slot-scope="props"
     v-for="slotName in pivotNames">
    {{ props.header.text }}
    <v-icon>
      mdi-pencil-outline
    </v-icon>
  </template>
```

**Script tag**

```js
  export default {
    name: "Product",
    data() {
        return {
          newHeaders: [...],
          products: [...],
          stockHeaders: [], //Have stock headers info
          pivotNames: [] //Used in the v-for
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getPivotHeaders() {
            const self = this;

            this.stockHeaders.forEach(function(stock, index) {
                let indexFound = stock["value"].includes("pivot.quantity");

                if (indexFound) {
                    self.pivotNames.push("header." + stock["value"]); //Create name for slot template
                }
            });
        }
    }
```